# How to optimize pandas groupby lookup?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe (150K rows) in which I groupby 4 columns and want to find rows where three columns matches particular values.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv',encoding="ISO-8859-1",dtype='unicode')

g = df.groupby(['col1','col2','col3','col4'])
 
for i in g.groups:
    if (str(i[0]) == 'text1' and str(i[1]) == 'text2' and str(i[2]) == 'text3'):
        print (str(i[4]))
```

The code takes about 2 seconds to do a lookup. How can I improve the execution time?

Comment: If this is a row-wise operation, why do you need to do any grouping here, hm?

Comment: You are right, I don't want to group for this. I grouped to see all possible combinations  and ended up using these. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: `df.loc[df["col1"].eq("text1") & df["col2"].eq("text2") & df["col3"].eq("text3")]`?

Comment: @hmhm One basic principle when working with pandas is to avoid manually writing for-loops. Whenever you start writing one, you should take a step back and think what would be the right way to proceed / which is the right function to use.

Comment: Thanks @politicalscientist.

Comment: @Hugolmn you're right. One must not code Pandas like the C language.